# Socrata response times

Tags: socrata, soda

I am planning on using data set that's available in SOCRATA platform. I am planning on hitting the REST endpoints instead of downloading and managing data on my own.

I have below questions.

- is there a guaranteed uptime?
- 1000 requests per hour is that a hard limit?
- do you have any metrics on response times?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: You have a good answer already but I think you'd do better asking Socrata directly for some of these. In particular if you have specific guaranteed uptime requirements that might be sometihng you'd have to pay extra for.

Answer (score 1):

Per your questions:

- *is there a guaranteed uptime* - You will want to check [Socrata's maintenance windows](https://support.socrata.com/hc/en-us/articles/202951578-Socrata-Maintenance-Window-Policy) to time any downloads.
- *1000 requests per hour is that a hard limit?* - 1,000 records per request is only applicable to version 1.0 of their API. [Version 2.0 has a maximum of 50,000 records and version 2.1 has no limit](https://support.socrata.com/hc/en-us/articles/202949268-How-to-query-more-than-1000-rows-of-a-dataset). [See how you can determine](https://dev.socrata.com/changelog/2015/11/25/soda-api-versioning.html) the API version for the dataset you are using.
- *do you have any metrics on response times?* - In my experience, it's highly variable, usually depending on your local ISP and network activity. Overnight and weekend jobs are usually faster while mid-day jobs are a bit slower. I'd recommend running some tests.

Comment: Thanks tom !!  For my second question i am looking for  allowed requests per hour. I got that information from “your application will be granted up to 1000 requests per rolling hour period. ” in https://dev.socrata.com/consumers/getting-started.html under throttling.

Comment: I've never seen or heard someone get throttled. An API key is not required, but using an API key is supposed to let you increase your requests because they'll email you if they have concerns. It is a soft limit.